# Determining the number of coin tosses to get $2$ heads in a row

Tags: probability

How many times do you have to flip a coin such that the probability of getting $2$ heads in a row is at least $1/2$?

I tried using a Negative Binomial: 
$P(X=2)=$$(n-1)\choose(r-1)$$p^r\times(1-p)^{n-r}  \geq 1/2$ where $r = 2$ and $p = 1/4$. However, I don't get a value of $n$ that makes sense.

Thank You

Comment: This question does not make complete sense.

Comment: @ncmathsadist I edited the Question. Hope its clearer now.

Comment: I'm not that well educated in probability, but I believe you would need a limit. The only probability you'll get of $\frac{1}{2}$ overall is getting either heads or tails on a single trail. The rest of the conditioning will give you probabilities below a half. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is not a negative binomial problem; it is more complicated.

Comment: The question wouldn't be more along the lines of "how many trails do you need to have at least 2 consecutive heads?"

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104649/counting-the-sequences-of-coin-flips-that-end-hh-after-n-flips-a-more-efficie

Comment: A more precise formulation might be:  Suppose we flip a coin $n$ times.  Let $p(n)$ be the probability the sequence has two consecutive heads somewhere.  What is the smallest value of $n$ such that $p(n) \geq 1/2$?  What is the context of the question (homework problem?)  Do you know about Markov chains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you toss a coin $n$ times, the number of different ways the result can *aovid* getting two heads in a row is $F_{n+1}$, where $F_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence, with $F_0=F_1=1$ and $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$.  So the crossover point is where $F_{n+1}/2^n\le1/2$, or $F_{n+1}\le2^{n-1}$.  This occurs at $n=4$, since $F_5=8=2^3$.

Comment: Thanks. However, isnt the number of sequences where no 2 consecutive heads appear if we toss a coin 1 time and 2 times, i.e. F1 and F2 equal to 2 and 3 respectively as with 1 toss we have H and T and with 2 tosses we have only HH out of 4 possibilities?

Comment: @Jojo, if you toss the coin $n=1$ times, the number of sequences with no 2 consecutive heads is $F_{1+1}=F_2=2$.  Likewise, if you toss the coin $n=2$ times, the number is $F_{2+1}=F_3=3$.  In general, the appropriate Fibonacci number to look at when you toss a coin $n$ times is $F_{n+1}$, not $F_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think you may think of it as a binary tree. The tree either splits towns $H$ or toward $T$. We want to find the level of the tree where $2^{n-1}$ nodes have at least double heads. There might be a neater way of doing this, but this works:

- Take the first trial. You get either $T$ or $H$.
- The next trail for each branch is either $T$ or $H$, giving the combinations $HH,HT,TT,TH$. We have 1 out of 4 branches that have a consecutive $H$.
- For the next step, we expand the branches again. Now we have 2 "original" branches that cover the requirement, spawning from the former $HH$ and a new one from $TH$, so that's $3$ out of $8$.
- We follow this idea and spawn doubles from the branches that fulfilled the condition. That's $4$ from the $HH$, and $2$ from the $HT$. That's $6$. Then we add $2$ from the branches of $TTH$ and $HTH$. That's eight out of sixteen.

So you need at least $4$ trials to be half sure of getting at least consecutive heads.

---

Don't take this too seriously yet! Work in progress. Suggestions are welcome.

Maybe you could model it as a propagating condition. So first you propagate one out of four, and with each level extra you get $2^{n-1}$ successful branches. Also, for each new level you add, you add $(n-2)$ successful branches. Then you make a sum a certain level:

$$
2^M + \sum_{k=1}^{M}k\ 2^{M-k}\
$$

where $M$ is the number of trials minus the number of consecutive heads you want. I'll try to prove it when I get some extra time.

Comment: Your solution is correct. The 8 "good" outcomes are HH**, THH*, TTHH, and HTHH, where the * is a wild card that can be either T or H.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This proof is **incorrect**. Please see the other proofs.

I'm no statistician, but I'll do my best to help you:

Consider some number of coin tosses $n$. With every $n$ coin tosses, there are $n-1$ opportunities to get heads two times in a row. Since with every coin toss there is a .5 chance of getting heads, there is a .25 chance of getting two heads in a row. Therefore, there is a .75 chance of not getting two heads in a row. Since the chance of getting heads two times in a row for $n$ trials is at least .5, the chance of not getting two heads in a row for $n$ trials is at most .5. Therefore, we get the equation $.75^{n-1} \leq .5$. Solving for the smallest value of $n$, we find that $n = 4$. Therefore, you would need to flip four coins in order to (likely) get two heads in a row. $QED$

Hope this helped. Please feel free to leave a reply if you need me to make something a little more clear.

Comment: Something like this might make sense if we consider pairs of flips and neglect cases of heads occuring across two distinct pairs. But if we consider individual flips, there are dependencies you are not considering.

Comment: @Michael Could you explain your response better? I don't think I am understanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: Your use of $(0.75)^{n-1}$ assumes you can multiply the probability of $n-1$ distinct events (each having probability $0.75$), but this only makes sense if the events are independent.  But they are not independent.   Given that I get two heads in a row in the first two flips (flips 1 and 2), the chance of me getting two heads in a row on flips 2 and 3 is equal to 1/2, not $1/4$.

Comment: You can model the problem by a discrete time Markov chain with states $\{START, H, END\}$, if you know about Markov chains, where the probability of transitioning from $END$ to $END$ is 1 (i.e., $END$ is a trapping state).

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. Clearly, I have not taken that many statistics courses :P